# What happens when I put a NOT NULL constraint in MySQL while importing a CSV file and the file contains NULL values?

Tags: mysql, csv

I am importing data from a CSV file to MySQL for the first time. Many tutorials I have seen recommends putting a NOT NULL constraint to all of the columns. I am not certain if certain columns don't have NULL values so I am only putting the constraint where I am certain there are no NULL values. But I want to know what would happen if there are NULL values in a column where I put a NOT NULL constraint? Would the values just display 'NULL' or would there be an error in importing the file?

Edit: I am using the LOAD DATA INFILE function to load the data.

Comment: How are you importing , are you using a wizard from some ide or LOAD DATA INFILE or something else?

Comment: I am using LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: I would go with what the manual says https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html